# Handling 401 Unauthorised response code in OTEL collector

Tags: open-telemetry

What is correct way to handle 401 unauthorised response from prometheusremotewrite?

I want to run a custom code to fetch latest authorisation credentials from an http endpoint when OTEL collector receives 401 response code from prometheusremotewrite URL. From what I saw, there isn't any hook possible to do this? I want to avoid cloning current exporter just to write this piece of code.

Comment: That sounds like OIDC. Am I right?

Comment: These are more like basic auth creds (username,password)

Answer (score 0):

OTEL collector has an interface for authentication https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/config/configauth/README.md

There is already basic auth extension - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/extension/basicauthextension
I would write only extension for your need, I wouldn't fork exporter.

Comment: I want to avoid pinging auth http endpoint unless the current credentials starts failing. We want to deploy thousands of these OTEL collectors deployed and want to avoid overloading auth http endpoint.
But there is no way authenticator knows what response code did the remotewrite endpoint returned. Hence, exporter seemed a better option (although not ideal, I  know)